# Make LocalSessionFactoryBean enforce read only on db connections

Tags: spring, hibernate, c3p0

Using spring/hibernate/C3P0 ComboPooledDataSource.  I am on a legacy project with spring 2.5, hibernate 3.3 and newest C3P0.

I am using LocalSessionFactoryBean implementation.

I use the spring TransactionInterceptor to globally set the transaction attributes.

I am adding a second replicated database to be used for reporting queries only.  This will be a read only database and I would like to set all the connections to be read only.

I was trying to create a second instance of LocalSessionFactoryBean that has data sources which reference secondary databases.
However, what I would like to do is set all these transactions to read only.

I was hoping there might be a way to do this in the ComboPooledDataSource datasource.  For instance the apache commons BasicDataSource has a readOnly setting.  The C3P0 one does not.

Next, I thought there might be a way to do it in the LocalSessionFactoryBean.  But no luck finding that.   Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a database account that only has read-only access.  That is the best way to guarantee that the user cannot write.  Create a second data source for that account and have at it.

Trying to do this with Spring/Hibernate is not the proper way to do it.  If you use the right tool for the job it will be much more clean, understandable and maintainable.

Comment: So essentially the user account should only have select privilege?

Comment: Correct, not sure which RDBMS you are using at the very back-end but here's an example of how to do it with MS SQL: https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.HOWTO16965.html

Comment: I am using postgresql.  I know how to grant only select privileges.  I was trying a lot of complex solutions.  I didn't think about this method of using the user to limit the access.  Thank you very much for this simple and clever solution.